# Populate cells with dates based on combo box selection and insert based on weekday

Tags: loops, date, combobox

I am not very good with excel - however, I am trying to create a good time accounting sheet that suits our complicated needs.

However, this is only a user feature: I have a cell (dropdown using input validation) with all the months. Upon selecting a month, I would like column C to be populated (1.1, 2.1, etc...). However, column B has the weekdays included (Monday to Sunday, repeating 5 times). The date column is supposed to be populated based on Weekday and date.

Example, B6-B12 = Monday - Sunday. 
If user input = January (2016) then, 
because 1st of January = Friday put 1.1 to C10 because B10 = Friday and 1.2 to C11 and 3.1 to C12 etc.... 
http://postimg.org/image/xj3vbxh8v/

Could anyone give me an idea on how I could accomplish something like that? 
TVM 
maul0r

Comment: please update your post with a screen shot of your data set up and your expected results. Also, if you leave the `excel-vba` tag, you are most likely going to have your question closed since you didn't provide any coding attempts. I have a feeling this can be done by using built-in Excel functions.

Comment: Also, your logic doesn't make sense. I understand `C10 = 1.1` (1st month and 1st day) and `C11 = 1.2' (1st month and 2nd day), but `C12 = 3.1` does not make sense. Should it be `C12  = 1.3` (first month and 3rd day)?

Comment: Ok - I removed excel vba. The workbook is already programmed in vba - which is why I choose that tag.
http://i.imgur.com/M83jQhy.png shows the layout of the sheet I am talking about. 
Again, If you select January (2016 implied for now) then detect what weekday (Monday - Sunday) it is, and start populating the cell. Does that help?
PS: Sorry I am talking european data scheme and it was supposed to mean 2.1 not 1.2 sorry :(. I should have explained that. DD/MM. Actually the current sheet displays date as 1-jan, 2-jan, etc...

Comment: Can you embed your link into your original post. When I click the link it comes up blank.

Comment: That's strange - it works for me.. Let me upload the picture somewhere else...
http://postimg.org/image/xj3vbxh8v/
Does this one work for you?

Comment: that one is blocked for me (which is a firewall issue), but I think I solved your issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see the screenshot of your data, but I did come up with what I think is a solution, based on your requirements.

I used the ranges you referenced in your description as best as I could, but you may need to adjust to suit your exact layout.

See the screenshot below (sorry it is not high quality, but I currently do not have my screenshot tool). Explanation of formulas is below the pic.

[image]

1. Assumes month drop-down list is in cell A1
2. G1 = `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),VLOOKUP(A1,$M$1:$N$12,2,0),1)`
3. H1 = `=TEXT(G1,"dddd")`
4. C8 = `=IF(C7="",IFERROR(INDEX($G$1,MATCH(B8,$H$1,0)),""),IF(MONTH(C7+1)=MONTH($G$1),C7+1,""))`
5. Drag C8 down to fill all rows of days.
6. You will need to add one more set of days to make sure all days are shown for all months.

*Note: I have not figured out yet how to stop days from repeating after the month is finished, but will edit once I get the solution.